# Keeping presentation (HTML) and logic (PHP) separate

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am trying to keep presentation and logic separate without using a template engine like Smarty.  What I have so far is working, but I am not sure how to do certain things without putting more PHP into my presentation than I would like to.  For example, right now I have something like this:

## product_list.php

```php
    try {
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, IFNULL(url, title) AS url, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category SEPARATOR ', ') AS category,
            FROM products p
            LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
            LEFT JOIN categories c ON pc.category_id = c.id
            WHERE p.active = 1
            GROUP BY p.id");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }
include('templates/product_list_tpl.php');
```

## product_list_tpl.php

```php
<div class="card">
    <div class="product-list with-header">
        <div class="product-list-header center-align">
            <h2><?= $header_title; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
            <!-- Some Product Info -->
            Category:&nbsp;<?= $row['category']; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example some products will have one category, some will have multiple.  They display nicely in a comma separated list, but I would like to make the category names into links.  I know I can do something like below, but it seems messy to me.

```php
<div class="card">
    <div class="product-list with-header">
        <div class="product-list-header center-align">
            <h2><?= $div_title; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
            <?php $categories = explode(', ', $row['category']); ?>
            <div class="product-list-item avatar">
                <img src="img/product/<?= $row['id']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?= $row['title']; ?>" class="square">
                <a href="product/<?= generate_link($row['url']); ?>" class="title bold"><?= $row['title']; ?></a>
                <p class="caption"><?= $row['caption']; ?></p>
                <div class="item-bottom">
                    <span class="responsive"><?= $row['description']; ?></span>
                    <p>
                        Category:&nbsp;
                        <?php foreach ($categories as $key => $category): ?>
                            <a href="category/<?= strtolower($category); ?>"><?= $category; ?></a>
                            <?= (sizeof($categories) > 1 && $key == end($categories)) ? ',&nbsp;' : ''; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <span>Rating:&nbsp;<?= $row['rating']; ?></span>
                        <span class="right">Rated&nbsp;<?= $row['rated']; echo ($row['rated'] == 1) ? '&nbsp;time' : '&nbsp;times'; ?></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.  Also, if anyone has any input on the general separation format I used on the example code I would love to hear it.  I am just getting back into coding after an 8 year break.

EDIT: Added missing `endforeach` and improved indentation on third code block as per @Devon suggested in comments.

EDIT: I updated the third code block to include HTML I previously left out and added all PHP functionality needed to achieve the output I am looking for.  It works, but IMO doing it this way removes the little separation I had.  I now basically just have one file with my database call and another file with this mess.  I feel like I am not going in the right direction for proper business logic / presentation logic separation.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is no real way around this, whatever template language you would use instead of php, it will always look similar to this, just with a slightly different syntax. IMO the only real advantage of using a templating language would be to restrict access to php in certain sections.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your example.  Iterating with foreach is perfectly normal for a view.  You just need to fix your indentation to make it a little more readable and make sure you close the second foreach.

Comment: @jeroen There can be many other advantages to templating languages.  Extending layouts and defining sections of content versus using includes is a huge one.  Some also like to remove PHP as a dependency in the presentation layer.

Comment: Any template language will need to have some level of logic integrated into it.  You can write functions on the controller side to use in the view to keep the logic down to a minimum though.  For instance, a function to output a list of categories, or output a category link.

Comment: @grimmdude You do not want to worry about output/formatting in your controller, that is a layer violation.   You can create functions in your presentation layer, but those should be separate from the controller.

Comment: @Devon I agree, but something tells me there's no presentation layer in this case.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  @Devon I figured a `foreach` or `if` here and there are acceptable, but it seemed like it was turning too much into spaghetti code with the  `$categories = explode(',', $row['category']);` and the nested foreach

Comment: @Jay it depends on your requirements.  There isn't an issue using PHP in your presentation layer as long as it's for output and formatting and not business logic.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lengthy, complicated logic such as:
`(sizeof($categories) > 1 && $key == end($categories)) ? ',&nbsp;' : '';`
shouldn't be in the view to bother a front-end developer. "What is this hideous line of code?
What does it do? Why didn't the back-end developer give me something easier to work with?" Part of the power of MVC is not only in separation of concerns, but
also keeping back-end and front-end developers' work separate.

Code like `<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>` contains no indication as to what it's working with. The DIVs, Ps, and SPANs are out of control as well.
This is why I'm a fan of view helpers.

**I'd suggest:**

> product_list_tpl.php

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="product-list with-header">
        <div class="product-list-header center-align">
            <h2><?= $div_title; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <?= displayItems($items); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The view helper used above:

```
function displayItems($items)
{
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $categories = explode(', ', $item['category']);
        $id = $item['id'];
        $title = $item['title'];
        $url = $item['url'];
        $caption = $item['caption'];
        $description = $item['description'];
        $rating = $item['rating'];
        $rated = $item['rated'];
        include('product_list_item_tpl.php');
    }
}
```

> product_list_item_tpl.php

```
<div class="product-list-item avatar">
  <img src="img/product/<?= $id; ?>.jpg" alt="<?= $title; ?>" class="square">
  <a href="product/<?= generate_link($url); ?>" class="title bold"><?= $title; ?></a>
  <p class="caption"><?= $caption; ?></p>
  <div class="item-bottom">
    <span class="responsive"><?= $description; ?></span>
    <p>
      Category:&nbsp;
      <?php displayCategories($categories); ?>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>Rating:&nbsp;<?= $rating; ?></span>
      <span class="right">Rated&nbsp;<?= $rated; ?>&nbsp;<?= isPluarl($rated)?'times':'time'; ?></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The view helpers used above:

```
function isPlural($number)
{
    return $number != 1;
}

function displayCategories($categories)
{
    $last = end($categories);
    $count = sizeof($categories);
    foreach ($categories as $key => $category)
    {
        $cat = strtolower($category);
        $isLast = $category == $last;
        include('product_list_category_tpl.php');
    }
}
```

> product_list_category_tpl.php

```
<a href="category/<?= $cat; ?>"><?= $category; ?></a>
<?= ($count > 1 && !$isLast) ? ',&nbsp;' : ''; ?>
```

Note I inverted the `$key == end($categories)` part from what you were using before with `!$isLast` and swapped `$key` to `$category`. This logic still feels dirty as two categories could have the same name. Probably better to just use `count($categories)` in conjunction with `$i++` to decide if it's the last loop.

**Edit:**
This works nicely and avoids the prior mentioned issue as it relies on the key rather than the value:

```
function displayCategories($categories)
{
    end($categories);
    $last = key($categories);
    $count = sizeof($categories);
    foreach ($categories as $key => $category)
    {
        $cat = strtolower($category);
        $isLast = $key == $last;
        include('product_list_category_tpl.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response!  This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.  It definitely helped get me on the right path of properly separating my logic.